# Old Linux kernel support for Android 5.0

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel

There's been a lot of buzz that Android 5.0(Key Lime Pie) which is expected to be released in the second quarter of 2013, will be based on Linux 3.8 Kernel. Does that mean older devices which have Linux 3.4 or 3.3 Kernels wouldn't be able to upgrade to Android 5.0?

P.S. If the question appears to be foolish, I apologize. I'm just a novice.

Comment: My guess is Android 5.0 doesn't actually _need_ Linux 3.8.  Otherwise they'll upgrade the kernel on your device (if supported).  I am not affiliated with the Android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand the basic interaction between the OS, drivers and the Kernel.

At the lowest level, you have the device drivers. For Microsoft, the driver model used goes in generations, where the design of the drivers is set, and then Microsoft has hardware makers come up with the drivers. Making it so Microsoft is not responsible for driver creation has made it a "not our problem if your device does not work" situation.

Once that base driver layer is taken care of, then you just need the rest of the OS to talk to that driver layer and scale with things like screen resolution and such. You may have noticed that video card drivers get a LOT of talk about quality, mostly between AMD and NVIDIA since Intel is NOT competitive in the graphics space(outside of the integrated stuff).

For the rest, it isn't a huge deal. Now, since the hardware companies don't make drivers for newer versions of mobile operating systems for older products, that makes it far more difficult to update older handsets, if not impossible.

You may remember the initial problems with Vista when it came to stability. NVIDIA did NOT have drivers ready, so what shipped with Vista was fairly unstable, and caused BSoD issues. Vista may have needed some work at release, but most of the real problems were caused by bad drivers(and people trying to run it with 1GB of RAM or less).

If/when Android makes it so the driver layer stays the same while the rest of the OS can evolve, that will help, but the Linux kernel itself has jumped to 3.4 relatively recently, and older drivers will not work without being recompiled for it, and again, the chip makers have NOT been very good about making drivers.

So, ultimately it's up to Android-OS developers and the chip manufacturers. If Android 5.0 uses advanced features of Linux 3.8 Kernel, then it may not support the older kernel versions. But the salvation always rests in the hands of chip makers, who can redefine(tweak) the OS code to suit the respective kernel version of the device.

P.S. If you are trying to root/flash the ROM in order to install the most recent OS, first check the compatibility with the target kernel, else chances are, you may end up with a bricked phone.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot really be answered until someone from the Android team comes along or the next version is actually released.

However, older devices which currently use an older kernel should be able to run this new one fine, assuming the hardware supports it and a ROM is made available for that device. The kernel version doesn't have to be the same across updates (Nexus S can run 2.3, 4.0 and 4.1, which use multiple kernels).

Comment: If it can not be answered, then why do you post an answer? Shouldn't this be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can also update Ubuntu which used different Linux kernels. Same for Android Phone. However it depends on manufacturers if they allow you to update and release one.